# Read maven properties from eclipse execution

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I'm developing a simple java application that needs to do some operation again a database. Now I have the foolowing trouble:

I defined some profiles in my pom and enabled the resources filtering:

```
.....
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Development</id>
        <properties>
            <db.driverClass>MyDriver</db.driverClass>
            <db.connectionURL>MyUrl</db.connectionURL>
            <db.username>MyUsername</db.username>
            <db.password>MyPassword</db.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
<profiles>
.....

<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

Now I also created a myProp.properties in src/main/resources where i defined the following properties:

```
driverClassName = ${db.driverClass}
url = ${db.connectionURL}
username = ${db.username}
password = ${db.password}
```

If I try to run **mvn install -P Development**, in the generated jar the maven variables are substituted correctly, but if I try to execute the program with Run->Java Application of eclipse the following snippet of code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myProp.properties"));
System.out.println(props.getProperty("driverClassName"))
```

I get **${db.driverClass}** instead of MyDriver.
Where Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to activate your profile in the eclipse build configurations.
Hope this page helps : http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.fr/2011/11/how-to-activate-maven-profile-inside.html#.VL0NPUeG9ps